# VBA Adding the phone prefix to phone number column based on country

Tags: vba, prefix, phone-number

I really need your help on creating a macro that will add the prefix to all the phone no cells in a specific column, based on the country information located into another column.

Based on the country in column J I want to add the country phone prefix to cells in column K. If the phone number already starts with the correct prefix it should leave it as it is.

I came up with something but it's very primitive and it just adds the same information to all the cells in the row... I am really stuck

```
Sub Add1()
ForEach r In Range("K2:K")
r.Value = r.Value +44
Next r
EndSub
```

This would be really helpful and save me tons of hours of manual work! I really appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: Sounds like a job for [VLookup](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1?CorrelationId=fcb25ab0-015b-473c-bfdb-56ebc4483802&ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB), which can just be a formula.

Answer (score 1):

So if you are looking to prepend "*44*" to each cell in a specified range, you can use something like this in your code:

```
For Each r In Range("K2:K30")
    If Not (Left(r.Value, 2) = "44") Then
        r.Value = "44" & r.Value
    End If
Next r
```

Note that I have specified an end to the `Range` (so "K2:K30"), then I check the first two characters of the value to see if it is "*44*".  If not, then "*44*" is prepended to the cell contents and the process loops.

Obviously you can replace "*44*" with whatever value you want (such as "*+44*" or other codes and values as appropriate).

Comment: Thanks Martin, this really helps but the thing that gives me headaches is the fact that daily I receive this file with phone no`s that have the wrong prefix and I have to manually verify each record depending on the country. This is what I am trying to solve :)

Comment: So if I want to add another If to the code, for the country? If country = France then add 33...

Answer (score 0):

### Formula Solution

Please note that this will work for any country as long as they are in the lookup table. Create a sheet called "Country_Codes" and create a table like below With column A being country and column B being the code

```
Country Code
Austria 43
United Kingdom  44
Denmark 45
Sweden  46
Norway  47
Poland  48
Germany 49
```

Countries(in column J) must match the above lookup table for this to work. They can be named as you see fit in the lookup table above. And good starting points can be found all over the net for country codes.

Then use a vlookup, I put the below in L2 (can be put in first empty column) and then autofill down with your data

```
=VLOOKUP(J2,Country_Codes!A:B,2,FALSE)&K2
```

---

### VBA Alternative

arr1 and arr2 need to be added to in tandem

```
Sub t()
Dim arr1()
Dim arr2()

arr1 = Array("Austria", "United Kingdom", "Denmark", "Sweden", "Norway", "Poland", "Germany")
arr2 = Array(43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49)

With ActiveSheet
    For Each cell In .Range("J2:" & .Range("J2").End(xlDown).Address)
        Found = 0
        For i = 0 To UBound(arr1)
            If cell.Value = arr1(i) Then
                cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = arr2(i) & CInt(cell.Offset(0, 1).Value)
                Found = 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        If Found = 0 Then
            'Country not found in arr1()
            NF = NF & "," & cell.Value
        End If
    Next
End With

If Len(NF) > 1 Then
    MsgBox "These countries could not be found :" & Right(NF, Len(NF) - 1)
End If

End Sub
```

Above will put the combined values in L. If want it to overwrite the values change

```
cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = arr2(i) & CInt(cell.Offset(0, 1).Value)
```

to

```
cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = arr2(i) & CInt(cell.Offset(0, 1).Value)
```

Comment: many many thanks moorem, I really appreciate taking your time for this reply. The idea is that I receive daily files with the wrong country code or missing and I need the macro to add it by default because I have hundreds of entries.

Comment: Above now has a VBA alternative too

Comment: Moorem you are the best, if i could send you a beer online, you would have a six-pack on your way right now :) the only thing is that I receive an error 6 overflow when I try to use it for the combining values in L.

Comment: Do you want to combine in K (e.g. overwrite the original phone numbers) or create a new combined phone number in L?

Comment: I want to combine in K the country code with the existing number if the phone no doesn't start with it already. If the cell is blank it should leave it as it is.